# Snowflake SQL: Get Last Day of Month Records

Tags: date, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Where one would normally use EOMonth, in Snowflake there is no such function. They have LAST_DAY, but so far I have not been able to get that one to work neither. Does anyone see what I have done incorrectly below **OR** have a workaround to EOMonth in Snowflake?

My attempts:

```
SELECT *
FROM "NORCO"."UNITS_SNAPSHOT" AS US1
WHERE US1.CCODE LIKE '%514-L%' AND 
US1.TIMESTAMP=(SELECT LAST_DAY(US1.TIMESTAMP,'MONTH') 
               FROM "NORCO"."UNITS_SNAPSHOT" AS US2 WHERE US1.CCODE=US2.CCODE)
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM "NORCO"."UNITS_SNAPSHOT" AS US1
WHERE US1.CCODE LIKE '%514-L%' AND 
US1.TIMESTAMP=LAST_DAY(US1.TIMESTAMP,'MONTH')
```

What I expect for the return from the daily records table is the last day of month records. Suggestions, help or ideas are appreciated!!

Thanks all

Comment: What do you get with those expressions? errors or incorrect data? does `timestamp` contain a time component? What datatype is it? Do you get what you expect when you just run `SELECT US1.TIMESTAMP, LAST_DAY(US1.TIMESTAMP,'MONTH') FROM "NORCO"."UNITS_SNAPSHOT" AS US1`

Comment: Yurp, that was it @Nick.McDermaid, I had to use their TO_DATE field on both ends to get it to function correctly. Thanks for the thought!

Answer (score 1):

I would be sure that the data types are identical, ie. `DATE`, so a minor change:

```
SELECT *
FROM "NORCO"."UNITS_SNAPSHOT" AS US1
WHERE US1.CCODE LIKE '%514-L%' AND 
US1.TIMESTAMP::DATE=(SELECT LAST_DAY(US1.TIMESTAMP, MONTH) 
                     FROM "NORCO"."UNITS_SNAPSHOT" AS US2 WHERE US1.CCODE=US2.CCODE)
```

I have a hard time understanding what this query is trying to achieve and why it has to be correlated.  Is it to look for a set of `CCODE` that have a `TIMESTAMP` of EOM?  If that is the case, some simplification:

```
SELECT *
FROM "NORCO"."UNITS_SNAPSHOT" AS us
WHERE us.CCODE LIKE '%514-L%' AND 
us."TIMESTAMP"::DATE=LAST_DAY(us."TIMESTAMP", MONTH)
```